# Why stacktrace is modified when you use throw in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [incorrect stacktrace by rethrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217616/incorrect-stacktrace-by-rethrow)

Hello,

until now I thought that doing:

```
int a = 10/0;
```

will create the same exception as

```
try
{
    int a = 10/0;
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

but it don't. If you use the second one the stacktrace will contain the throw line as the point where the exception was raised. In this example is not a problem but when you have a real method you don't know where the exception was raised.

This is the MSDN information:

> If an exception is re-thrown by
>   specifying the exception in the throw
>   statement, the stack trace is
>   restarted at the current method and
>   the list of method calls between the
>   original method that threw the
>   exception and the current method is
>   lost. **To keep the original stack trace
>   information with the exception, use
>   the throw statement without specifying
>   the exception**.

Is this really the expected behavior or is this a .Net bug or what? How can I preserve the REAL stacktrace? I could create a new Exception putting ex as the InnerException but that's:

- Ugly.
- Longer.
- Makes you choice the rigth exception to throw.